# Create static folder by nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

trying to create static folder by node js but i getting error cannot get /videos

my attempt

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = require("./router");

const app = express();

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/videos", express.static("videos"));

app.use(router);

const port = 7780;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

http://localhost:7780/videos/

Cannot GET /videos/

Comment: `express.static` allows files in a folder to be accessed, it doesn't provide an interface for browsing those files.

Comment: Like @PádraigGalvin said you will be not able to browse that files. If your folder will be not empty then you will be able to fetch/download particular files.